# Load data incrementally in azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am still wondering if there is any way to copy the data from one data lake folder to another data lake folder using copy activity or dataflow activity in the Azure data factory.

Suppose, I have a file in my input folder that says input/employee.csv which has data till March 21 and I have loaded that data into my datalake in the output folder output/employee.csv.

Now, from the next run onwards, I only want to pull data that got modified in the last 7 days. For doing that I queried the source system and I got that 7 days of data in a file and now, I need to check that 7 days of data against my sink and merge the data accordingly to sink (update/insert/delete).

I checked upsert if in dataflow but it looks like to work on this we need sink as a DB, but here my sink is datalake even my source is the file present in datalake.

I think I can use merge file behaviour or hashing as well, but not sure what will be the more optimized approach?

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

There is a source property in both Copy & Data flow for "last modified date/time". You can also use the pipeline incremental pattern with waterlines or hashing techniques.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GACpvMjOJgE
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-overview

Comment: Thanks, Mark, but here I am not targeting the change data capture, I had my new data in the source file (say 10 rows) and I want to merge the data to the sink file. currently, my sink has 100 rows so after merge I am expecting around 110 rows (all insert records )

Comment: If you are trying to append data to a file in the lake, you will need to either use the Delta Lake format or a database sink. Your other option, which is sub-optimal, would be to read the entire original file into a sink and then union that with your new results. Your output sink would then be a new file that combines the old file data with your new data.

Comment: my source is adlsgen1 and I think delta lake format is available for blob storage and adlsgen2

Comment: In the case of union it will create two records for the same id, if it is updated, I only want to keep updated records

Comment: Union is not ideal. But in lieu of using Delta or a database feature, this is what you have available to you. You would need to execute a follow-on dedupe process to address record duplication.